# Javascript filereader is not working at all

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am a beginner, doing my project. Part of my work is read a file from local in to html file. So I wrote the code below which from internet. But it's not working at all. My firefox gets nothing back on the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My first styled page</title>
</head>
<body>

<script> 
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
var text = reader.result;
document.querySelector('body').append(text);
};
reader.readAsText(README, "us-ascii");
</script>

<!-- Site navigation menu -->
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="alamode-fetch">Alamode</a>
<li><a href="README">Readme</a>
<li><a href="town.html">My town</a>
<li><a href="links.html">Links</a>
</ul>

<!-- Main content -->
<h1>My first styled page</h1>
<p>Welcome to my styled page!
<p>It lacks images, but at least it has style.And it has links, even if they     don't go anywhere&hellip;
<p>There should be more here, but I don't know what yet.
<!-- Sign and date the page, it's only polite! -->
<address>Made 5 April 2004<br>
  by myself.
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the html file. So still nothing after add those code in script.

Comment: firefox gets nothing back, cause you put nothing. Try at least `console.log(text)` after you set value of text, or `alert(text)` if you are not familiar with the console

Comment: Also that `us-ascii` should be a string constant - `"us-ascii"`

Comment: Still not working, I guess I've something wrong with the whole script. Let me post it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifiying anything on the page, just reading a file in your script, try appending your text to the body for exemple or logging it in the console.

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var text = reader.result;
  document.querySelector('body').append(text);
  //Or console.log(text)
}
```